# Atualização mensal para os dias 30 e 31 em um intervalo de datas

Tags: php

O que tem de errado na minha fórmula para sair o resultado abaixo? Queria que tivesse resultado para todo dia 31 e ir corrigindo o mês que não houvesse dia 31.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++){
    $tempo = strtotime('03/31/1990'.'+'.$i.' month');
    echo date('d/m/Y', $tempo);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
31/03/1990
01/05/1990
31/05/1990
01/07/1990
31/07/1990
31/08/1990
01/10/1990
31/10/1990
01/12/1990
31/12/1990
31/01/1991
03/03/1991
31/03/1991
```

Comment: É para ficar fixo o dia 30 ou 31 isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A forma correta de fazer isso seria usando `DateInterval` ou `DatePeriod`.

Veja um pequeno exemplo:

```
$start    = new DateTime('2010-12-02');
$end      = new DateTime('2012-05-06');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Veja funcionando no [`IDEONE`](http://ideone.com/lZr7QP)

Outra forma para saber o último dia de um mês é usando a string `last day of this month`.

Veja:

```
// pega do mês atual
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('last day of this month'));
```

Ou

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '01/2015');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Com certeza, :D +1

Comment: Obrigado @rray. Alguém formata o código pra mim, estou com pressa